# Can't login after full system upgrade

Tags: linux, 64-bit, arch-linux, kde-plasma-5, wayland

yesterday i upgraded my system on Archlinux and after a reboot the login screen is back whenever i type the pass, password is right but i think there's some error somewhere dunno.
i tried my best to solve it so i switched to tty3 (alt+shift+f3)
and ran

```
startplasma-wayland
```

and noticed the error it was about symbol lookup error in /usr/lib/libKWaylandServer.so.5 which is a symbolic link to newly install version of this library
and when i was doing upgrade it said Warning qt5-* (version) is newer than extra (version).

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

i used this command to upgrade and it succeed. but everytime i login it throws me back to login screen

Comment: Please, try create a **new user** and so try logging on with it. Then, tell us if you managed that one.